# Greatest Value in a Dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to find the greatest value in the highlighted column of this access database. I have tried a few ways of doing it but none of them work.

[image: table]

I need to use **LINQ**. Preferably the `from x in y [...] select x;` statement. If I cannot to this with the aforementioned then anything using **LINQ** would probably suffice. If you could explain why your answer works that would help me out a lot.

Edit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


 namespace CarStatistics
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblCarsTableAdapter.Fill(this.honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars);

        }

        private void btnCarAmount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCarAmount.Text = "Our inventory consists of " + (dgvCars.RowCount - 1).ToString() + " cars!";
            lblCarAmount.Visible = true;
        }

        private void btnMstExpensive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to find Max
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You learn more by doing the coursework yourself.

Comment: @buffjape I do, but sometimes I don't understand and need help from outside sources.

Comment: Show the few ways that you have tried.  Why do you _need_ to use Linq?

Comment: @DStanley Because the chapter I am on requires it...

Comment: You should always try to include code in your question where possible. Either what you have already tried or at least things like the definitions for your data sources or similar. At the moment my answer assumes your data is in a structure that implements `IEnumerable<T>` but we don't know this for sure which means answers may not actually work for you. Also if you show your current failed attempts then it also helps people answering to tailor their answer to address your problem more specifically.

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate linq method to use would be `[Enumerable.Max][1]`. There are many overloads but the ones you will want are either the one that works on an `IEnumerable<decimal>` (assuming that that type of your column is decimal). This would be used as:

```
source.Select(x=>x.Price).Max()
```

`source` would be the IEnumerable that you have the data in and `x.Price` assumes that the value of that column is obtainable through a property called `Price`.

The other alternative would be using the overload of max that takes a `Func<TSource, decimal>` to tell it what data to use for the max:

```
source.Max(x=>x.Price)
```

I'm not sure there is much difference apart from in readability. I'd probably be inclined towards the first, particularly since in the first draft of this question I got wrong what the second actually returns (Thanks to Robert McKee for correcting me on that). :)

Comment: Both of those return exactly the same result, which is only the price.  The second version does not return the entire record(s) which has the maximum price as your description seems to imply. In order to return the entire record, you could do `source.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Price).FirstOrDefault()`, but that won't return multiple records if they exist.

Comment: @RobertMcKee: You are quite right, I misread the method signature as returning `T` rather then `decimal`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
var maxPrice = db.Items.OrderByDescending(i => i.Value).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

This works by ordering all of the rows based on the column specified, then takes the first row from that list, and selects the value of that column.

Comment: What using statement does that need?

Comment: How are you obtaining the data? Entity Framework? SqlDataReader?

Comment: I am just using the data wizard in VS. I don't know what that would be. Is it different based on the method you choose?

Comment: No - just curious. So do you already have a context to the data source in your code?

Comment: In case optimisation is important using `Max` should be more efficient than ordering the entire data set, the reason being that `Max` can find the maximum in a single pass of the source (O(n)) whereas the sort will be worse than that. Another way to intuitively see this is that with Max it finds the highest and stops - that is it doesn't care what order the rest are in - whereas ordering the entire list means you need to order all the things you don't care about as well.